# How to mock custom JdbcCursorItemReader during individual step unit testing on Spring Batch?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to create a Junit test case for testing an individual step of my batch Job which in turn has a custom `JdbcCursorItemReader` and writes data into Flat file. I am unable to mock the data that can be injected into the processor for writing it into the Flatfile. Please help.

I followed steps in below link to create a test case to launch an individual step:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/testing.html

Since my reader component is stepscope I am using the context around section 10.4 in above link to put the required domain objects into `ExecutionContext` but while launching the step it does not recognize the same instead it executes the actual SQL query which I am injecting through config xml.

My config xml has step as below :

```
<step id="sample-step" next="next-step">
 <tasklet>
    <chunk reader="customJDBCReader" processor="customProcessor" 
     writer="customFlatFileItemWriter" commit-interval="XXX" />
 </tasklet>
</step>
```

My customreader implements `JdbcCursorItemReader` which has a SQL defined for reading information from database.

During my unit testing I am trying to mock the data instead of depending on actual data from database

```
private StepExecution execution;

@BeforeStep
public StepExecution getStepExection() {
    execution = MetaDataInstanceFactory.createStepExecution();
    return execution;
}

@Test
public void testSampleStep() throws UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, Exception {
    MyDomainObject domainObject= new MyDomainObject ();
    domainObject.setID("sampleID");
    domainObject.setName("sampleName");
    domainObject.setImage("sampleImage");
    execution.getExecutionContext().put("someKey", domainObject);
    execution.setReadCount(1);

    JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("sample-step", jobParameters, execution.getExecutionContext());
    AssertFile.assertFileEquals(new FileSystemResource(EXPECTED_FILE), new FileSystemResource(OUTPUT_FILE));
}
```

The expected result should be the launchstep needs to get the data from `executionContext` instead of database to write the same into faltfile.

Comment: You said your reader is step scoped. What is it consuming from the execution context? Are you using the `StepScopeTestExecutionListener`? Please share your reader's code as well as your test class.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine thanks for replying, my reader executes a dynamic SQL from config which returns n records w.r.t my MyDomainObject. I do have the StepScopeTestExecutionListener but  my jobLauncherTestUtils always executes the real query to feed the results for my step. I am unable to mock or override the  results of my custom reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expectation is wrong. If the step uses a `JdbcBatchItemWriter`, this reader will still issue a SQL query during the test, **regardless** of whether you mock the data in the execution context or not. The input data of a step is different from the data stored in the execution context.

In such scenario, I would recommend to use an embedded database in your test and populate it with some dummy data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your update! yes I recently realized the same, will try to mock my data using embedded database to fix this problem.